# Setup git over ssh in Rubymine on Windows

Tags: windows, git, ssh, rubymine

I found a lot of threads about how to setup git over ssh with msysgit and putty/plink, but rubymine seems to use its own git and ssh implementation (see error message below).

Currently I have putty, msysgit, TortoiseGit and rubymine installed. My repository has two remotes:

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = ssh://mygituser@255.255.255.255:1234/path/to/repo.git
[remote "origin_putty"]
    url = putty-alias:path/to/repo.git
    puttykeyfile = path/to/my/putty/keyfile.ppk
```

In putty the connection "putty-alias" is defined with the same user, host and port used in `origin` and also sets the ssh key again (might not be necessary). Using TortoiseGit to push to `origin_putty` works fine since it loads the putty ssh key and prompts for my passphrase. However, when I'm trying to use `origin` from rubymine it prompts for the password of `mygituser` since there is no keyfile defined.

I already tried the following solutions

- Setting GIT_SSH to plink, running pageant and loading the key there (no change)
- using the `puttykeyfile` line in the definition of `origin` (no change)
- using `origin_putty` from rubymine (does not resolve `putty-alias`)

The reason I think rubymine uses its own ssh implementation is the error message I get on an unsuccessful authentication:
SSH: authentication methods: [publickey, keyboard-interactive, password] last successful method:

```
java.io.IOException: Authentication failed: 
    at org.jetbrains.git4idea.ssh.SSHMain.authenticate(SSHMain.java:280)
    at org.jetbrains.git4idea.ssh.SSHMain.start(SSHMain.java:155)
    at org.jetbrains.git4idea.ssh.SSHMain.main(SSHMain.java:135)
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right: by default RubyMine uses trilead-ssh2 Java library, and is not aware about Putty settings.

You may switch to using the native SSH in the Settings | Version Control | Git | SSH Executable | Native
But note, that it doesn't work well with passphrases, so if your private key is passphrase protected, you have to use pageant or similar software.